# How do I call a controller from jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I'm trying to call a controller (I'm using codeigniter) from my js script (using jquery) and it's been harder than I expected.

The controller function is meant to delete some item from the database. To do this I just call the function using jquery's post or get (I tried both).

Since I'm using codeigniter I figured the easiest way to do this is to pass the arguments through the URL and then get them in the controller ($this->uri->segment(NUMBER);)

So my get request would look something like this:

```
$.get('my_function/'+item_id);
```

my_function is in the same controller I'm calling it from, so there are no problem with the URL (I clarify this because at first I wrote the whole /index.php/my_controller/my_function and threw an error)

Like I said, my_function is meant to delete an item but it wasn't doing so, therefore I decided to check whether my script was calling my_function by writing this at the very beginning of the function:

```
echo 'hello';exit;
```

But the 'hello' never appears, which only means that is not calling the function.

I remember many years ago I made this jquery/codeigniter combination work, so there's something I'm doing wrong here and I have no idea what it is.

Thanks in advance for the help.

MODIFIED:
More information: I trigger the $.get() method when the user clicks on a certain kind of class

```
$('.my_class').click(function(){
$.get('my_function');
});
```

Comment: How about add my_function to route? Didn't you forget it? Before trying to call ajax, test just URL by typing it in your browser.

Comment: When you navigate to my_function/(item id) mandually, does the script work?

Comment: When I type the URL to go to my_function on the browser, it works just fine, only says 'hello' like is supposed to

Comment: see in your console what url is hitting by your ajax call

Comment: I used the inspect feature in Chrome, went to the Network tab and then clicked on the class that triggers the $.get() method. It throws back a 200 status which means success and I can see the URL that it's loading and it's exactly the one I want to load. It says that the Initiator is jquery.js:9664 don't know if that's of any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```
var url = "<?php echo base_url('name_of_controller/my_function/'); ?>"+item_id;
$.get(url);
```

(this works if you removed the 'index.php' from .htaccess). You can check with firebug the URL called and check if it's the one you desired, but I always made that way to work either with $.get() & $.post().

UPDATE

Try this, is a simple example that should work, if doesn't work, share the .htaccess file and the output of this:

JS:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var url = "<?php echo base_url('test/hello_function'); ?>";

        $('.class').click(function(e){              
            e.preventDefault();
            $.get(url,function(data){
                alert(data);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

CI:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed: login');   
class Test extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function hello_function(){
        echo "HELLO!!!";
    }
}
```

Comment: It gave me a 404 error, the resource wasn't found, and apparently doesn't even process the PHP. The only way it doesn't give me the 404 error is when I write the name of the function alone, that's the URL that I want, believe me, I'm getting that part right.

Comment: Ok, this is clearly a URL problem (404). Try to add  your .htaccess and the info from the url generated. Maybe this works because you have specified a default countroler, but the jquery doesn't know the CI controller that "belongs" and is a good practice to use the base_url() function. I suggest you to open the terminal and check the url generated. What's happens if you hit directly the URL from the browser?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help JP Aulet. I answer the exact same question that you asked me in the comments right above. Hope we are close to getting somewhere with this. Once again thanks for your help :)

Comment: The PHP in your example doesn't get processed (at least in my app). I get a 404 error and the by seeing the URL that is not getting loaded I can tell the PHP code is not getting processed (the blank spaces and other special characters get converted to hex)

Comment: Execute manually the url like: http://localhost/yoursite/test/hello_function . Iit prints a blank page with HELLO!!! ? I guess you have a problem with URL routing. If this NOT work, you have a problem with URLS. Then try: http://localhost/yoursite/index.php/test/hello_function . Try adding more information to search the root of the problem.

Comment: I made a video showcasing my problem, hope it helps https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f2zIUpEUdxQ

Comment: Your function `del_producto_carrito()` is being called, but the 'hola' word is not show because you don't print it with the '$.get' function, but it's processed. I suggest you to delete the 'exit(0)' and try to put different alerts (i.e: hola1,hola2,hola3) to know the "deep" that you get. 

You have: `if($this->uri->segment(3) ... (4))` this should be: `segment(1)` and `segment(2)` (check: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html)

Then the query should process.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106647/discussion-between-fedejp-and-jp-aulet).